# Make an HTTP Request from a browser, without sending any cookies in the request headers

Tags: javascript, cookies, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible to make a request from a browser, preferably using the built-in XMLHttpRequest API, "WITHOUT" sending any cookies in the request headers?

As far as I understand setting the "allowCredentials" property to false will only disable cookies for CORS requests, where I want to make a request to the same server while not sending a "Cookie" header.

I know this sounds a bit strange, but because of current project constrains I do not have the ability to alter the Server to change the "path" in the "Set-Cookie" response header.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/mozAnon

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a way to exclude cookies for a single request.

If you know the names of the cookies and they will not be needed by other requests later, you can delete their values like this:

```
document.cookie="COOKIENAME=";
```

The cookie names will still be there though.

If you need the values later, you can save the cookies to a variable:

```
var cookie = document.cookie;
// Delete the cookie values like above.
// Make a request without cookie values.
document.cookie=cookie;
```

But if you need to make requests with and without cookie values at the same time, this will obviously not work. And if the cookies have the HTTPOnly attribute, you will not be able to read them or change their values.